# Sleep in javascript, why doesn't it loop?

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

I was wondering why the common code for sleep functionality for javascript doesn't loop

`await new Promise(resolve =>{setTimeout(resolve, 5000)});`

it assigns resolve an arrow function that runs resolve itself after 5 seconds. so why doesn't this recurse or loop?

Comment: Why should it recurse or loop. What is the resolve function??

Comment: Why would it? The "sleep" only occurs once here.

Comment: doesn't it schedule to call the `resolve` arrow function to run after 5 seconds? which it self  schedules it to run after 5 seconds?

Comment: No, it calls `resolve` once and that's it. If you want this to repeat, you'll need an explicit loop: `for (;;) .. your code ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resolve` is a function, generated by `Promise`.

To put it simply, `resolve` internally marks the `Promise` as resolved.

But that only happens once. **You cant `resolve` a `Promise` twice.**

Once a `Promise` got resolved, it "triggers" (dunno, if it's the correct word) given `then`, `catch`, `finally` callbacks.

Comment: isn't `resolve` only an arrow function I wrote to exactly do one thing? set a timeout? Or does the `Promise` modify it to add some code to mark the `Promise` resolved?

Comment: @Abraham - No, `resolve` is a parameter you've declared for your arrow function, not a function you created. See the reply I've given you on my answer.

Comment: No. The function you define is the one you give to the `Promise` constructor: `resolve => {..}`. And that function recieves the generated `resolve` function as an argument which you then have to call yourself in your defined function (`resolve => {..; resolve(); ..}`). You even recieve a second argument: `reject`. Which is also a generated function, but instead of resolving, it rejects (and thus, triggers `.catch` instead of `.then`)

Comment: yes, that was my big misunderstanding, Than you!

Answer (score 1):

There's just no reason for it to. The event system will trigger the call to `resolve` after approximately five seconds without any need for a loop, which will fulfill the promise.

Comment: doesn't issue another schedule when the event system calls `resolve`? since `resolve` is an arrow function to set timeout to run `resolve` it self?

Comment: @Abraham - No. From another comment elsewhere you seem to think `resolve` is an arrow function created by your code. It isn't, it's a *parameter* to an arrow function your code creates. Your arrow function is called once by `new Promise`. `new Promise` calls your arrow function passing in a function for that parameter that will resolve the promise. You're then passing that function to `setTimeout` as its callback, so about five seconds later the function `new Promise` gave you is called with the value `undefined` which fulfills the promise.

Comment: yes, that was my big misunderstanding, Than you!